# Animation Mixamo's FBX in blender

Tags: animation, import, .fbx

[image]

I'm trying import the character and animation from mixamo in blender.
Default pose my character is A-pose, but Mixamo's animation is T-pose.
Hand's bone is error when run animation.
Here's what happen when i try to run animation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and managed to fix it by doing this:

First you need to scale your model correctly to the size you want in Blender. Then while in object mode press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and apply scale, rotation and location.
After that, export your model as an .obj.

Import it into Mixamo, animate it and then export it as a .dae.

Now, import the .dae into blender. Re-scale the model to what you had it as before and then it should work.